# Backup S3 bucket with identical links

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Question Bank application with +10k questions.

The questions are a combination of text (stored within a database) and images (hosted on Amazon S3). The images are embedded as links through a admin panel.

For security purposes, I want to figure out if I can back-up the entire S3 bucket and later restore it with the **same identical links**.

Any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that your users are accessing the images via an Amazon S3 URL.

The URL consists of the bucket name and the Key (filename) of the object. To provide a file with the "same identical link" simply means **putting it in the same bucket and giving it the same Key**.

Please note that **data stored in Amazon S3 is replicated between multiple Availability Zones**. Therefore, it is typically not necessary to backup data for resilience purposes. However, it can be wise to backup in case somebody accidentally or maliciously deletes the objects. (Turning on [Versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) could also be a way to safeguard against such cases.)

If you do wish to "backup an entire bucket", one option is to use [Same-Region replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html), which will automatically replicate objects between buckets. It requires that Versioning is activated.